# MongoDB .find() returning null when documents are present

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am very new to MongoDB and I am currently following [a blog tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/mern-stack-tutorial/) that teaches me how to build a website using the MERN stack.

**The Issue**

The issue is with the backend, especially retrieving documents from the backend. I inserted a document into the database myself (via the website) for testing. It sits in a collection called "Articles":

```
_id:613c75edd38cd146c0b8a1df
title:"An experimental evaluation of test driven development vs. test-last de..."
authors:"Munir, H., Wnuk, K., Petersen, K., Moayyed, M."
source:"EASE"
pubyear:"2014"
doi:"https://doi.org/10.1145/2601248.2601267"
claim:"code quality improvement"
evidence: "strong support"
```

**My Files**

Below is the Article Database Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const ArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: {
        type: Number
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    authors: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    source: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    pubyear: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    doi: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    claim: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    evidence: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }


});

module.exports = Articles = mongoose.model('Articles', ArticleSchema);
```

Here is the routes:

```
// routes/api/articles.js

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Load Articles model
const Articles = require('../../models/Articles');
console.log(Articles);

// @route GET api/articles/test
// @description tests articles route
// @access Public
router.get('/test', (req, res) => res.send('articles route testing!'));

// @route GET api/articles
// @description Get all articles
// @access Public
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  Articles.find()
    .then(articles => res.json(articles))
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ noarticlesfound: 'No articles found' }));
});

// @route GET api/articles/:id
// @description Get single articles by id
// @access Public
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
  Articles.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(article => res.json(article))
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ noarticlefound: 'No article found' }));
});

// @route GET api/articles
// @description add/save articles
// @access Public
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  Articles.create(req.body)
    .then(article => res.json({ msg: 'Article added successfully' }))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json({ error: 'Unable to add this article' }));
});

// @route GET api/article/:id
// @description Update article
// @access Public
router.put('/:id', (req, res) => {
  Articles.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body)
    .then(article => res.json({ msg: 'Updated successfully' }))
    .catch(err =>
      res.status(400).json({ error: 'Unable to update the Database' })
    );
});

// @route GET api/article/:id
// @description Delete article by id
// @access Public
router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
  Articles.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, req.body)
    .then(article => res.json({ mgs: 'Article entry deleted successfully' }))
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ error: 'No such a article' }));
});

module.exports = router;
```

Backend works perfectly. When I go to the test route it returns the expected string. But it seems it always returns an empty collection (`[]`) when retrieving anything.

My app.js file:

```
// app.js

const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
var cors = require('cors');

// routes
const articles = require('./routes/api/articles');

const app = express();

// Connect Database
connectDB();

// cors
app.use(cors({ origin: true, credentials: true }));

// Init Middleware
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello world!'));

// use Routes
app.use('/api/articles', articles);

const port = process.env.PORT || 8085;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

**What I have tried**

Most of the issues I see on Stack Overflow seem to do something along the lines of db.collection.find yet in this tutorial it doesn't say anything about retrieving data like that so I was unable to try most of the fixes.

I did notice in the Articles collection the id is actually _id, so I made that change to the database model for articles and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a format that I usually follow but could you include this modification and check if it works? 
I tried it with a different DB and it works for me.

```
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
  Articles.find({}, function (err, allDetails) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.json(allDetails);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried it and unfortunately got the same result

Comment: I have updated the code. Do check it out.

Comment: I appreciate all your help by the way! But same issue, it is still returning an empty result. I am completely lost at this point.

Comment: I managed to sort it all out. I first tested my backend with an online api tester and it kept returning error 400. I have done quite a bit since then, so I do not really remember what the issue was. I did realize that the reason I could not submit articles was because I was not putting in all the variables that the article database model had. It was around that time that I figured out the other error.